# Closing questions due to lack of knowledge

Tags: discussion

This question has an answer:

[Why doesn't Doc use the DeLorean in order to escape from the Libyans?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77915/why-doesnt-doc-use-the-delorean-in-order-to-escape-from-the-libyans?noredirect=1#comment128491_77915)

It's a very specific answer covered in the movie, spoken by a main character.

I'd like to know why this question was closed?  And if it was closed because the voters didn't know the answer (or didn't know an answer existed) then we need to do a little better policing this, because some good questions that obviously aren't widely understood run the risk of getting deleted and moved into the netherworld of later pages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to reverse my vote...perhaps I was influenced by the comments underneath...my vote was, it seems, "the last nail in the coffin" which ended up closing it.

I've voted to re-open but that has **always** been an option for others and at the time of writing, *mine is the only one*.

*Hand in the air...I got this one wrong!*

Comment: I haven't looked into that question yet, but *"mine is the only one"* already deserves a +1. It seems to question isn't that controversial at all. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

*Voted to reopen.*

There is definitely a fine line between this sort of good question and "The answer to this question is because the script writer wrote it that way". In my opinion, there is no problem here. @JohnnyBones stated he has a valid answer to this, which puts it in the former category. So now we reopen it.

I am standing by to upvote a good answer to this valid question.